# WNDA3100 wireless adapter has stopped working under Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I had got my usb wireless adapter working using the ndiswrapper approach, but since a batch of updates it has stopped working. It no longer lights up and no longer connects to the network I had it configured to use The version of Ubuntu I am using is:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

And the output of lsusb is:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bc2:2332 Seagate RSS LLC 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0111 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Card Reader
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0846:9011 NetGear, Inc. WNDA3100v2 802.11abgn [Broadcom BCM4323]
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52e Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

I'm fairly new to linux, so any general advice on how I can get it working again would be brilliant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else encountered this, I had to build and install ndiswrapper again after updating the kernel. The wifi dongle worked fine after this.